# How to make a custom range slider in flutter with non uniform discrete divisions?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, rangeslider

i want to make a range slider in flutter which has variable discrete divisions. For example in normal slider divisions are like- 0-10,10-20,20-30,30-40 ......100.Here 1/10 length is given to each division. But i want to make a range slider in which divisions are like 0-10,10-50,50-100. so 1/3 length given to all these 3 divisions.

normal slider-
this slider shows all number between 1-100.change in value per division is constant.

```
0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
```

what i want to make-
this slider also shows all numbers between 1-100. but slider will go slowly from 0-10, then faster from 10-50, then more faster from 50-100.

```
0       10        50         100
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
```

Actually in my project i want to make a slider such that the we can choose easily the numbers from 0-1000(100 per divisions), then after that the speed increases from 1000 - 100000(1000 per divisions) and then 100000-1000000(100k per divisions). these 3 in one range slider.
This is the best way i can explain the problem.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderTickMarkShape-class.html - the docs say: *"Base class for Slider tick mark shapes.

Create a subclass of this if you would like a custom slider tick mark shape."*

Comment: @pskink i dont want to create a custom slider tick mark or tooltip, please read the question properly.

Comment: ok, but how can i create custom tick marks, and the doc u mentioned is about customtickmark shape.

Comment: @Artisted,, did you find the solution,,, I'm facing the same issue and can't find a solution

Comment: i used flutter_xlider package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider

Comment: and then i made a function, which will convert linear values(0-100) according to the client's need, the slider will hv 100 normal break points, but it will show different values

Comment: String convert(double value) {
    String result = value.toInt().toString();
    double temp;
    if (value <= 50) {
      temp = value * 1000.0;
      result = convert(temp);
    } else if (value > 50 && value <= 60) {
      temp = ((value - 50) * 5000) + 50000;
      result = convert(temp);
    } else {
      temp = ((value - 60) * 25000) + 100000;
      result = convert(temp);
    }
    return result;
  }

Comment: here value ranges from 0 to 100 linearly, so u can create a function of this type according to ur need. and u can use this function to show the converted value in a text widget

Answer (score 0):

More of a workaround, but this should work.

```dart
final mapper = {0:0, 1:5, 2:10, 3:50};

...

Slider(
  min: 0.0,
  max: 3.0,
  divisions: 3,
  value: _value,
  divisions: 10,
  label: '${mapper[_value]}',
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _value = value;
      returnValue = mapper[_value]
    });
  },
)
```